# Elasticsearch query serialization using Java client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, serialization

I'm using *official* **Elasticsearch** client for Java. It works nice, but unfortunately its objects do not implement **Serializable** interface. I need to serialize instance of **QueryBuilder** in particular.

I've discovered two ways of serializing objects using the client. One of them is to use **QueryBuilder.writeTo()**. The other one is to use:

```java
Strings.toString(queryBuilder.toXContent(XContentFactory.jsonBuilder(), ToXContent.EMPTY_PARAMS))
```

But I cannot find how to **deserialize** object in both cases.

Also I'm not sure whether it is a *best way* of solving the task.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do that?

Comment: @GhostCat I need it to pull data from ES into Apache Flink nodes using sliced scroll - it requires serializable queries.

Comment: My usecase is to cache ES-queries that are generated with quite some effort.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I ended up with the following code:

**Serialization:**

```java
// wrap query with source to deserialize any type of query
SearchSourceBuilder query = new SearchSourceBuilder().query(this.query);

String sourceJson = Strings.toString(query);
```

**Deserialization:**

```java
private static final NamedXContentRegistry xContentRegistry;

static {
    SearchModule searchModule =
        new SearchModule(Settings.EMPTY, false, Collections.emptyList());

    xContentRegistry =
        new NamedXContentRegistry(searchModule.getNamedXContents());
}

...

XContentParser parser =
        XContentType.JSON.xContent().createParser(xContentRegistry,
                                                  LoggingDeprecationHandler.INSTANCE,
                                                  sourceJson);

SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = SearchSourceBuilder.fromXContent(parser);

this.query = sourceBuilder.query();
```

So, you can add this code to `readObject()` and `writeObject()` methods to provide (de-)serialization for ES query object.

Implemented using **Elasticsearch 7.5.1** client library.

Comment: Works like a charm. You can also avoid the detour over SearchSourceBuilder and use `AbstractQueryBuilder.parseInnerQueryBuilder(parser)` for deserialization.